# Migration in Entity Framework Core - not updating the database

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using a domain first approach. I created an asp.net core MVC project and added a Products.cs in the model folder

```
  Products.cs
   -----id
   -----Name
   -----Rate
```

Now I ran the following commands in package manager console

```
  add-migration addedProducts
  update-database
```

There are no errors in the console manager

A database was created in the MS-Sql server
Now I add another entity in the Models folder called Audit.cs

```
  Audit.cs
   --- public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string OldValues { get; set; }
    public string NewValues { get; set; }
    public string AffectedColumns { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryKey { get; set; }
```

Now I repeat the steps in the package manager console

```
  add-migration audit
  update-database
```

There are no error messages.

I dont see a table called Audit in the database.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you added the table in the DbContext?

Comment: You need to have an Entity referencing to the audit class or as @MartinStaufcik suggested you need to add the `DbSet<Audit>` to the `DbContext` in order to tell ef core to add the table to the database...

Comment: nope. I didnot add any. should i add   public DbSet<AuditMVC.Models.Audit> Audit { get; set; } in ApplicationDbContext file?

Comment: Yes you have to add `public DbSet<Audit> AuditDbSet { get; set; }` to the DbContext.cs File. I would recommend to revert the second last migration (audit) and re-run the migration after adding the line to the DbContext just to keep things more organized and in one work line.

Comment: You need to add the new table in DbContext and then migration again.